# Difference between GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_ADDRESS_NV and GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ADDRESS_NV

Tags: opengl, nvidia

In: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory.txt

under `void BufferAddressRangeNV(enum pname, uint index, uint64EXT address,
                                   sizeiptr length);`

In the extension it states:

```
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ADDRESS_NV and <index> identifies 
    the generic vertex attribute whose address is being specified.
```

I thought that `VERTEX_ARRAY_ADDRESS_NV` was a generic vertex attribute. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic vertex attributes are [user-defined vertex shader attributes](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Attribute). Things like `gl_Vertex`, `gl_Color`, and so forth are *not* generic vertex attributes (though NVIDIA implementations will illegally alias generic attributes with them).

`VERTEX_ARRAY_ADDRESS_NV` is the address that feeds the built-in attribute `gl_Vertex`.